# Qual operador devo utilizar no c:if de JavaScript quando quero ficar entre duas variáveis?

Tags: javascript, html5, if

Senhores, preciso saber qual operador devo utilizar no c:if de Javascript quando eu quiser tomar uma decisão entre elas mesmas, por exemplo, preciso que um fundo de uma Div fiquei vermelha quando estiver entre a data x e y, gostaria de saber qual é o operador "ENTRE", segue um trecho do meu código.

```js
<c:if test ="${realizadoVN dfim <> dtini && ${realizadoVN <metaVN}">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="marca" ><h1>VN</h1></div> 
  <div class="meta"style="font-size: 25px;">META: <fmt:formatNumber value = "${VN.rows[0].META}" type="currency"/></div>
  <div class="rel" style= "background-color:red; color:white; font-size:30px;">ACUMULADO <br><br><fmt:formatNumber value = "${realizadoVN}" type="currency"/><br><h1> <c:out value="${VN.rows[0].ACUMULADO}"/>%</h1></br></div>
 </div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Não sei que linguagem é essa que vc está usando, mas não seria `dini <= realizado && realizado <= dfim`?

Comment: Kadu, e a meta que seria a segunda condição entraria a onde nesse caso? pois eu tenho duas condições no mesmo laço de decisão. <c:if test ="${realizadoVN dfim <> dtini && ${realizadoVN <metaVN}">

Comment: Como é tudo _and_ `&&`, é só colocar depois sem problemas. Só pra mim entender, realizadoVN é a sua data?

Comment: A data está sendo representada pela variável DTINI e DTFIN ( Data inicial e Data Final) o realizadoVN é a variável que recebe o valor do meu faturamento. O que eu gostaria na verdade era de uma função dentro do JavaScript onde eu pudesse saber o ultimo dia do mês e com isso subtrair menos 7, caso saiba seria bem vindo, pois essa solução que estou tentando aplicar nesse momento eu realizei diretamente pelo SQL e estou tentando trazer para a minha aplicação, por isso a questão inicial.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma excelente biblioteca Javascript chamada [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) para se trabalhar com datas, segue um exemplo:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('dataInput');
var div = document.getElementById('minhaDiv');
  
var dini = moment().endOf('month').add(-7, 'd');
var dfim = moment().endOf('month');

document.getElementById('certoSpan').innerHTML = dini.format('DD/MM/YYYY')
document.getElementById('cuidadoSpan').innerHTML = dini.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' ~ ' + dfim.format('DD/MM/YYYY')
document.getElementById('ruimSpan').innerHTML = dfim.format('DD/MM/YYYY')

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var data = moment(input.value);
  

  
  if (data.isBefore(dini, 'd')) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    div.innerHTML = 'Tudo certo! :)';
  } else if (data.isBetween(dini, dfim, 'd', '[]')) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    div.innerHTML = 'Cuidado! :|';
  } else if (data.isAfter(dfim, 'd')) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    div.innerHTML = 'Deu ruim! :(';
  }
  
  

});
```

```css
#minhaDiv {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="minhaDiv">MINHA DIV</div>
<input type="date" id="dataInput">
<p>Tudo certo até <span id="certoSpan"></span></p>
<p>Cuidado entre: <span id="cuidadoSpan"></span></p>
<p>Deu ruim depois de: <span id="ruimSpan"></span></p>
```